# Different font types in pdflatex and latex-dvips-ps2pdf chain

Tags: fonts

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\parbox{8cm}{\blindtext}
\end{document}
```

When I compile this code snippet using latex-dvips-ps2pdf and using pdflatex directly, I get (slightly) different results.

Result of **latex-dvips-ps2pdf** chain

[image: latex-dvips-ps2pdf]

Result of **pdflatex**

[image]

The PDF generated with the latex chain has font **CM10 Type 1C**, while the file generated using pdflatex has **CM10 Type 1** acording to evince.

Indeed, the font looks slightly "bolder" with CM10 Type 1C and seems to be easier to read on a screen. Furthermore, some people confirmed that this printed out document looks "nicer" than that generated with pdflatex (no microtype, etc. used).

**How can I achieve the same "look" as with the latex-dvips-ps2pdf chain, when using pdflatex?**

P.S.: This equally well extends to lmodern and probably other packages.

Comment: What distribution are you using?

Comment: TeX Live 2015 (pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015))

Comment: I don't think that you can force pdftex to store the fonts in type1C. And I don't see any difference in the output in the adobe reader and with sumatra - only the file sizes of the pdf are different.

Comment: I don't have those two programs installed, but I can confirm that the difference is also there with okular. On top, the printed out versions are different, where I uploaded the two PDF directly on the web-interface of my Dell printer.

Comment: The reason for the different appearance is answered [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305258/xelatex-font-rendering-tend-to-be-slightly-bolder-compared-to-pdflatex/337122#337122). The difference in printer output is surprising, but perhaps even the printer treats the font formats differently and isn't sufficiently high-resolution for the differences to go away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if this cannot be done directly using pdflatex, the desired effect (as well a significant reduction in file size) can be achieved by post-processing the pdflatex file using

```
ps2pdf -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dSubsetFonts=true old.pdf new.pdf
```

Comment: But `ps2pdf` is not a good solution since it may corrupt the text part (in particular for PDF files obtained with `pdflatex`), and the Ghostscript developers do not care very much about that; see [Ghostscript bug 704478](https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=704478). And nowadays, you also need `-dPrinted=false` to keep hyperlinks (but you will lose print-only annotations, if any). In short, `ps2pdf` is an ugly way to solve a particular issue.