# Why PDF-via-PS has heavier font than direct PDF?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, latexmk, ps2pdf, ps

I compile the same tex using two commands:

```
latexmk --pvc --pdfps ./main.tex
```

and

```
latexmk --pvc --pdf ./main.tex
```

Then view both pdf files using evince, at the same scale (170%).
The result using `--pdfps` (on the left) has heavier font that the result using `--pdf` (on the right):

[image]

**Do you know why?**

*Update*:
Here comes a minimal example:

```
$ cat main.tex
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\title{Compare}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
$$
a_\textit{ivanov} \wedge b_\mathit{sidorov} \rightarrow \text{petrov}^{2^{x}}
$$

\end{document}
```

Running `pdffonts` gives:

```
$ pdffonts ./pdf.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
JADGUW+CMR17                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       4  0
GFYLUX+CMR12                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       5  0
IEHANU+CMMI10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       6  0
WLJBIP+CMTI7                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       7  0
GHNOGE+CMSY10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       8  0
UWWUVN+CMR10                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       9  0
RKDUWA+CMR7                          Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no      10  0
EUVFVQ+CMMI5                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no      11  0

$ pdffonts ./ps.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
RRWQTJ+CMMI5                         Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no      22  0
EBFDMR+CMR7                          Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no      20  0
AFJYHC+CMR10                         Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no      18  0
ILWBCN+CMSY10                        Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no      16  0
OFQOVE+CMTI7                         Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no      14  0
IEOASN+CMMI10                        Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no      12  0
LWIAFV+CMR12                         Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no      10  0
ZGILVG+CMR17                         Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no       8  0
```

The `--pdfps` version uses Type 1C fonts, which may be the reason...

Comment: what does the output of `pdffonts` utility report?

Comment: We probably need to know about which fonts you're using, please provide a minimal example. Also, have you checked which fonts are actually used in the two pdfs? (pdffonts on Linux can help)

Comment: added no-so-minimal example and info about the fonts. The fonts type (type 1 vs type 1c) differs. Maybe that is the reason.

Comment: Type 1C fonts can contain "better" hinting data which is more appropriate for low-resolution display devices like computer screens. You will probably find that if you zoom in, the differences disappear, and they also disappear if you print the files (assuming you have a modern printer, not an ancient low-resolution one!)

Comment: @alephzero perhaps make that an answer?

Comment: @alephzero i confirm: when zoomed in at 300%, there is no noticeable difference. When printed, there is no noticeable difference. I wonder why pdflatex does not use Type 1C fonts by default, but that is a different story.

Answer (score 1):

I flagged my question as duplicate of the following:
[XeLaTeX font rendering tend to be slightly bolder compared to PDFlatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305258/xelatex-font-rendering-tend-to-be-slightly-bolder-compared-to-pdflatex)
which has the excellent answer:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/337122/18193

The comment by @alephzero helped to find this out, thanks!
As @alephzero wrote, Type 1C is a (lossless) compacted version of Type 1 fonts,
but with better "hinting" (hinting is used at low resolutions).
The difference disappears, as predicted by @alephzero, at higher zoom (300%, no noticeable difference), and on the printed versions of the documents.

Also, my version of evince seems to have different rendering engines for Type 1 and Type 1C fonts (see the above answer link), with Type 1C rendered producing a bolder result. The above linked answer also noted that there is no noticeable difference since Ubuntu 16.10.

Also related questions and sources:

- [Different font types in pdflatex and latex-dvips-ps2pdf chain](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272548/different-font-types-in-pdflatex-and-latex-dvips-ps2pdf-chain)
- [Fonts look different compiled by latex vs. pdflatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225617/fonts-look-different-compiled-by-latex-vs-pdflatex#225623)
- http://rastertragedy.com/
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/MzjKLF2x1Vo